# Wait for async validators to finish angular forms

Tags: angular, asynchronous, angular-reactive-forms, angular-custom-validators

I have an angular form with custom aync validators
I want to do some stuff if the form is invalid on load.

Here is the code

```js
ngOnInit() {
        this.signupForm = this.fb.group({
          name: [
            'Prasad P',
            [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(3)],
            ValidateUserNotTaken.createValidator(this.signupService)
          ],
          email: [
            '',
            [Validators.required, Validators.email],
            ValidateEmailNotTaken.createValidator(this.signupService)
          ]
        });
    
        // watch for status Changes
        this.signupForm.statusChanges.subscribe(status => {
          alert('Form Status Is ' + status);
    
          if(status === 'INVALID') {
            // do_stuff();
          }
        });

  }
```

The statusChange event never emits a value when loaded once I change anything in form then the event emits and everything works but I really want to know the form is invalid on loading.

I try to run *updateValueAndValidity()* but it always hangs to *PENDING* state.

The stackbliz Link : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-async-custom-validation-vlz43u?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code in stackblitz and I added *`updateValueAndValidity()`* after form has been created and it is working fine as expected. Please see this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-async-custom-validation-ovxwgc?file=src/app/app.component.ts).

The other alternative is you can patch your form values to your form to trigger the validation on page load. In the code below, I added `setTimeout(() => { this.signupForm.patchValue(this.signupForm.value);});` to trigger the validation on page load. You need to add this after you created the form.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.signupForm = this.fb.group({
      name: [
        'Prasad P',
        [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(3)],
        ValidateUserNotTaken.createValidator(this.signupService)
      ],
      email: [
        '',
        [Validators.required, Validators.email],
        ValidateEmailNotTaken.createValidator(this.signupService)
      ]
    });

    //Added to trigger form validation
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.signupForm.patchValue(this.signupForm.value);
    });

    // watch for status Changes
    this.signupForm.statusChanges.subscribe(status => {
      alert('Form Status Is ' + status);

      if (status === 'INVALID') {
        // do_stuff();
        console.log('TEST');
      }
    });
}
```

Comment: It works for OOTB validators but when it came to custom validators it always emits a PENDING status.
I have updated the stckBliz link to show custom validator